# how to link a_blank pages (with images)

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a set of pictures, when I click in one of them,  I manage to build an image reference so another page opens in a new tab or a new window and my browser is displaying the picture.

My question is:

How I can link this `a` `_blank` pages (with images) with each other, like gallery.

Comment: You can achieve that by using Javascript.

Comment: but how? I m familiar with html and css. :(

Comment: Look, this topic can help you with your problem. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536653/onclick-on-a-image-to-navigate-to-another-page-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank, Altay, but not Javascript. Maybe later.

Answer (score 1):

Use a link:

```
<a href="yourimage.png" target="_blank"><img src="yourimage.png" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.     I use your cod, but it doesent connect the blank pages, like a gallery.      http://www.ultramedika.rs/galerija.php

Comment: You need to use Javascript to do that like a gallery. You can't do much just by using HTML.

Comment: ok, can you help me then to insert javascript in my page. How to name script element and adapt script to my page.:)                                                                                                           I have thumb (small) , and preview (big) images.

Comment: @Sonja there are plenty of 3rd party ones out there. please do some research and let us know if you have a coding problem with them. we aren't here to write code for you.

Comment: Sorry for  disturbance and disconvenience... I m just curious if I have to use javascript.:)