# How to make an image inside a chat bot iframe, enlarge or go full screen on click when you cannot add id's or images attribute to the src image url?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have a chat bot that I am working on that is using websdk and the images are added through a tool from Oracle which will not accept image attributes, you just put the image urls in the correct fields. However the images are resized to the tiny chatbot iframe and I would like to figure out how to enlarge them on click or hover. Outside of the tool I can apply Javascript and CSS, I just cant edit the HTML as far as I can tell because it's rendered by the tool.
Here is what the tool looks like, see how its not using HTML, you just input the links?
[Oracle Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlIAU.png)

I used hover CSS and that words to enlarge the images but the image is still stuck inside the iframe sized so its not a real solution.

```
.oda-chat-card-image:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(2);
```

[Hover Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMhIE.png)

I found some code that puts the image into a target div which is the whole background iframe. I use this iframe to open links in the background of the chat bit that the bot suggests so the used stays in the same window. Which I like, but it requires the images have inline attributes that I cannot add.

I thought if I could use some Javascript to add the attributes to all images that I could get what I want but that seems to require adding unique IDs to the images but that is something I cannot do. I wondered what other possibilities anyone else could suggest.

The images do have a class so perhaps I can access them that way somehow. That's how I was able to apply the hover CSS class=oda-chat-card-image

This is the code I tried to use for opening the image on click in the background iframe which I named name="mainPageIframe" id="mainPageIframe"

```
const change = src => { 
    document.getElementById('mainPageIframe').src = src
```

If I inspect the image in the browser and manually add

```
onclick="change(this.src)"
```

to the end of an image,

Example code rendered by the chatbot tool but edited where I added the onclick attribute manually while in f12 inspecting the image.

```
<img dir="auto" class="oda-chat-card-image" src="https://eservice.xactware.com/esc/showme/images/Annotated/1379/Bot/X1ForgotPassword.png" onclick="change(this.src)" alt="Card image">
```

[Example of adding the attribute manually to produce the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C89Cz.png)
then when I click the image it opens in the background iframe. Doing this is the best thing I could think of but I would rather have the image open as an enlarged overlay over the whole screen instead of trapped inside the iframe. That's why I thought copying it to the main page iframe would be a solution. Any ideas on how I can apply

```
onclick="change(this.src)"
```

to all images in my webpage without unique id's or perhaps apply a different solution all together?

This is the HTML file I am working on that I can edit. It calls the bot contents by the URI and channelID. I am able to apply CSS to the items in the bot and Javascript, I just don't know how to get the images in the bnot to pop up or out side of the chatbot iframe and enlarge.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>ODA Live Chat Example</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe name="mainPageIframe" id="mainPageIframe" src="https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/digital-assistant/index.html" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:0;">
            Your browser doesn't support iframes
        </iframe>
        <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=Number.isInteger%2Cdefault"></script>

<style>
        
        
.oda-chat-card-image:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(2);


  
}       
.more
{
    display: none;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.oda-chat-conversation {
    background-color: #b3b8bd;
}
 
.oda-chat-left .oda-chat-message-bubble, .oda-chat-left .oda-chat-message-header, .oda-chat-left .oda-chat-message-footer, .oda-chat-card, .oda-chat-message-global-actions .oda-chat-action-postback {
    background-color: #2e5a81;

}

.oda-chat-message-actions {
    background-color: #1f3b54;
}

.oda-chat-message-global-actions .oda-chat-action-postback, .oda-chat-message-actions .oda-chat-action-postback {
    background-color: #1f3b54;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.oda-chat-action-postback {
    background-color: #1f3b54;
}

.oda-chat-header {
    background-color: #1f3b54;
}
.oda-chat-footer {
    background-color: #1f3b54;
}
.oda-chat-card-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


.oda-chat-button {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
  .oda-chat-button {
      height: 96px;
      width: 96px;
  }

        </style>
        
        <script>

const change = src => { 
    document.getElementById('mainPageIframe').src = src 
}


        
            //Function to toggle full pargraph showing
            function showHideParagraphs(lidx) {
                var dots = document.getElementById("dots"+lidx);
                var moreText = document.getElementById("more"+lidx);
                var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn"+lidx);
                btnText.blur(); //loose focus

                if (dots.style.display === "none") {
                    dots.style.display = "inline";
                    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
                    moreText.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    dots.style.display = "none";
                    btnText.innerHTML = "Show less";
                    moreText.style.display = "inline";
                }
            }

            //Function to split paragraphs with show more:
            var gidx = 0;
            function splitParagraph(txt) {
                var paragraphs = txt.split("\n\n");
                if (paragraphs.length > 1) {
                    var html = "<p>"+paragraphs[0]+'<span id="dots'+gidx+'">...</span></p><span id="more'+gidx+'" class="more">';
                    for (var idx = 1; idx < paragraphs.length; idx++) {
                        html += "<p>"+paragraphs[idx]+"</p>";
                    }
                    html += '</span><div class="oda-chat-message-actions"><button class="oda-chat-action-postback" onclick="showHideParagraphs('+gidx+')" id="myBtn'+gidx+'">Read more</button></div>';
                    gidx++;
                    return html;
                }
                else {
                    return txt;
                }
            }

            //For typing indicator for keepTurn messages
            var moreToCome = 0;
            var typingIndicatorSafeguard=null;
            function increaseMoreToCome(n){
                moreToCome += n;
                if (typingIndicatorSafeguard!=null){
                    clearTimeout(typingIndicatorSafeguard);
                }
                typingIndicatorSafeguard = setTimeout(function(){moreToCome=0;}, 30000); //In any case only keep generating typing indicators for 30 seconds
            }
            function decreaseMoreToCome(){
                if (moreToCome>0){
                    moreToCome--;
                    setTimeout(function() {Bots.showTypingIndicator(30);}, 0);
                }
            }
            //End of for typing indicator for keepTurn messages



            var delegate = {
                beforeDisplay: function(message) {
                    if (message.messagePayload.type=='text'){
                      //Split paragrahps with show-more
                      message.messagePayload.text = splitParagraph(message.messagePayload.text);
                    }

                    //Typing indicator for keepTurn messages
                    //Solution pending: https://bug.oraclecorp.com/pls/bug/webbug_edit.edit_info_top?rptno=30944113
                    if (message.messagePayload.text && message.messagePayload.text.match((/^((Greetings)|(Salutations)).*I am Artie/))){
                        increaseMoreToCome(2);
                    }

                    decreaseMoreToCome();
                    //End of typing indicator for keepTurn messages

                    return message;
                },
                beforeSend: function(message) {
                    //For typing indicator for keepTurn messages
                    moreToCome=0;
                    //End of for typing indicator for keepTurn messages
                    return message;
                }
            };

            var chatWidgetWebSettings = {
                URI: 'oda-12e973c924a245abbd61f357fbbe926a-da2.data.digitalassistant.oci.oraclecloud.com',
                channelId: 'a61c229b-5469-4ea0-b62c-686bc3c1ad76',
                enableClearMessage: true,
                enableLocalConversationHistory: true,
                enableTimestamp: true,
                enableAttachment: false,
                showTypingIndicator: true,              
                enableSpeech: true,
                enableBotAudioResponse: true,
                //openLinksInNewWindow: true, //Disabled as it's not really needed and is superseeding link onclick handler added through delegate.
                enableAutocomplete: true,
                disablePastActions: 'none',
                delegate: delegate,
                botButtonIcon: 'images/RbotIcon.png',
                botIcon: 'images/RbotIcon.png',
                logoIcon: 'images/RbotIcon.png',
                personIcon: 'images/personIcon.png',
                agentAvatar: 'images/woman2.png',
                i18n: { "en": { chatTitle: 'Oracle Digital Assistant',
                          chatSubtitle: "Help on digital assistant learning"
                        }
                },
                typingIndicatorTimeout: 30,
                messagePadding: '10px',
                //theme: WebSDK.THEME.redwood-dark,
                theme: 'redwood-dark',
                linkHandler: { target: 'mainPageIframe' },
                enableDraggableButton: true
                
            };

            function initSdk(name) {
                // Default name is Bots
                if (!name) {
                    name = 'Bots';
                }
                setTimeout(function (){
                    const Bots = new WebSDK(chatWidgetWebSettings); // Initiate library with configuration
                    Bots.on('widget:opened', function() {
                      console.log('Widget opened!');
                      if (Bots.getConversationHistory().messagesCount < 1){
                        console.log("Starting the conversation");
                        Bots.sendMessage('Hello', { hidden: true });
                      }

                    });
                    Bots.connect()                                  // Connect to server
                        .then(function (){
                            console.log("Connection Successful");
                        })
                        .catch(function (reason){
                            console.log("Connection failed");
                            console.log(reason);
                        });
                    window[name] = Bots;
                });
            }
        
        </script>

        <script src="files/web-sdk_21.02.js"  onload="initSdk()"></script>


        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I’m a bit confused by what you can and can’t get access too. Could you put up a minimal reproducible example, perhaps with just a couple of images in the iframe and show exactly how you managed to enlarge them, albeit within the iframe.

Comment: Go read up a bit on how adding event handlers without falling back onto “old-school” HTML attributes works. _Event delegation_ is one of the keywords you might want to look into here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956717/how-to-addeventlistener-to-multiple-elements-in-a-single-line should get you started.

Comment: @AHaworth, I added 3 images I hope that helps apply some context.

Comment: Could you read up about how to produce a minimal reproducable example on StackOverflow and put one into your question? Thanks. I'm afraid I still don't understand where you put the code and how you were altering the iframe contents - or was it just in the browser's inspector? In paticular, is the iframe src in the same domain

Comment: @AHaworth this was browser inspector. I added HTML code to the post. The chatbot is called by var chatWidgetWebSettings. Its running on my local machine with nodeJS. The Javascript you see includes something about separating long paragraphs which was in a tutorial from oracle and effects the bot for example. I am using linkHandler: { target: 'mainPageIframe' }, to get links to appear in the background iframe. I need help writing javascript that will change all links to have onclick="change(this.src)" on the end automatically. Or another idea on how to enlarge the images on click.

Comment: In another comment by Anthony Grist in this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536653/onclick-on-a-image-to-navigate-to-another-page-using-javascript/8536816  he says "That assigns an onclick event handler to every image on the page. " I think that is what I want but how to I modify it to have the onclick also onclick="change(this.src)" ?

<script>
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    image.onclick = function(event) {
         window.location.href = this.id + '.html';
    };
}
</script>

Comment: I found a solution on github if anyone ever needs to see the answer https://gist.github.com/hysysk/3473035/revisions